# How can I build a loop Expression to iterate a collection member on an object

Tags: c#-4.0, collections, expression

Looking at [ToStringBuilder](https://github.com/chillitom/ToStringBuilder/blob/e969b83868a87fbf11df84a82c749c34d55a5565/ToStringBuilder.cs) by chillitom I thought I'd like to extend it by making it so that a call to Include() on a property or field which is itself a collection type will result in looping though the collection and (effectively) calling ToString() on each child item in the collection (actually calling String.Builder.Append() but you get the idea).

I need some hints as to how I'd write an expression to look through the content of the collection taking the MemberExpression provided to the Include() method as the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Just "coding" in the answerbox here, so none-tested code, but I think you want something like:

```
public ToStringBuilder<T> Include(IEnumerable<T> collection, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
{
    var builder = new ToStringBuilder<T>();
    foreach(var item in collection)
    {
        builder.Include(item, expression);
    }
    return builder;
}
```

Else I guess I don't really understand what you want

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to clarify the question. We don't have access to an instance of the collection, only a MemberExpression.